# How can I write a test case that verifies that the function is being called correctly when the data prop changes using React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test case for a functional component that uses the useEffect hook in my React application using React Testing Library. My component looks like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { doSomethingWithData } from './utils'


function MyComponent({ data }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomethingWithData(data)
  }, [data])

  return <div>{data}</div>
}
```

How can I write a test case that verifies that the doSomethingWithData function is being called correctly when the data prop changes using React Testing Library?"

```
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should call doSomethingWithData when data prop changes', () => {
    const mockDoSomethingWithData = jest.fn()
    const { rerender } = render(<MyComponent data="initial data" doSomethingWithData={mockDoSomethingWithData} />)
    rerender(<MyComponent data="new data" doSomethingWithData={mockDoSomethingWithData} />)
    expect(mockDoSomethingWithData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('new data')
  })
})
```

Comment: Where is `doSomethingWithData` declared? If it is external to `MyComponent` you could just simply mock the function and assert it was called a specific number of times with specific args. Please [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] for all code you are trying to use/reference, including the unit test code.

Comment: It's an imported function, now edited the code

Comment: And the test code? Have you tried anything just yet?

Answer (score 3):

In the unit test file you can mock the `doSomethingWithData` function and make assertions on it. It may look something along the lines of the following:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { doSomethingWithData } from './utils';

// Mocks the module
jest.mock("./utils" () => ({
  doSomethingWithData: jest.fn();
}));

...

it("should call doSomethingWithData with updated data prop value", () => {
  const { rerender } = render(<MyComponent data={/* valueA */} />);

  expect(doSomethingWithData).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(/* valueA */);

  rerender(<MyComponent data={/* valueB */} />);

  expect(doSomethingWithData).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(/* valueB */);
});

...
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, let me verify.